# Is it possible to read a hdd that is hibernated if I start the computer from USB (Linux)

Tags: encryption, hibernate, windows-11

My laptop runs Windows 11 and I also have an Ubuntu partition. Is it possible to start from USB Linux and read win partition if hibernated?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But the question looks off-topic to me.

Comment: READ is safe, but don't forget files that were in the RAM of the hibernated machine (*thus changes made may still be in buffers saved in the hibernate file*) MAY READ incorrectly to the running OS due to *UNCLEAN* file-system...  Consider carefully what you were running (on screen & background!) on the hibernated OS before touching your files as you may be getting outdated or corrupted data because of UNCLEAN state of *fs*.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can mount it read-only and extract files from it.

You can not mount a dirty file system writeable and "hibernate" means dirty.

If you need to write to it you would need to delete the hibernate file loosing all info that is in it and that has not been saved to disk.

To remove the hibernation file use [ntfsfix](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ntfsfix):

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdaN
```

where sdaN is your hibernated partition. Use `sudo lsblk` to list your partition to find the one you need.

You should have it installed as part of ntfs utilities but in case it is not:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ntfs-3g
```

Comment: You can mount it ro with no problems. `ntfsfix` probably will break the hibernation.

Comment: Hmm that is true :D darn it.